# How to get a specific data from your database using Session?

Tags: asp.net, session, code-behind

I want to get a specific data from my database when login. The default login username for my web page is a student ID. Example (studentid="2011018921") this is the username that I declare when logging in, but I want to get a specific data in my database when I login to the system, like I want to get the firstname of the student.

this code here gets the data of the username.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class OnlineAppSyss : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private MSConnector connector = new MSConnector();
        string query = null;
        string clear = "";
        int rowcounter = 0;
        private DataSet selectedData;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connector.ConnectionString = "Data Source=keith;Initial Catalog=Student;Integrated Security=True";

            string username = (this.UserName.Value);
            string pass = (this.Password.Value);

            query = "select studentid,password from student";

            selectedData = connector.ExecuteQuery(query);


            for (;;)
            {
                string userid = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["StudentID"].ToString();
                string password = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Password"].ToString();
                //Username and Password are correct
                if ((username == userid) && (pass == password))
                {
                    //This session Login I want to get the firstname of the student
                    Session["login"] = userid;

                    Response.Redirect("StudentPage.aspx", true);
                    break;
                }
                //admin side, correct username and password
                else if ((username == "admin") && (pass == "cmpe1234"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx");
                }
                //admin side, correct username invalid password
                else if ((username == "admin") && (pass != "cmpe1234"))
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again1');</script>");
                    break;
                }
                //empty username and password
                else if (((username == "") && (pass == "")) || ((userid == null) && (password == null)))
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password must have input value. Try again2');</script>");
                    break;
                }
                //username is invalid and password is correct ; username is correct and password is invalid
                else if (((username != userid) && (pass == password)) || ((username == userid) && (pass != password)))
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    rowcounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is where I check my username in another aspx code behind to see the studentid log.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class StudentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Session["login"]==null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //it states here (Welcome 2011018921)
                labelsession.Text = "Welcome  " + Session["login"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I change my code to state (Welcome Keith) instead of a studentID declare it to FirstName.

I guess this is something to do with this code here?

```
        string userid = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["StudentID"].ToString();
        string password = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Password"].ToString();
        //Username and Password are correct
        if ((username == userid) && (pass == password))
        {
            Session["login"] = userid;

            Response.Redirect("StudentPage.aspx", true);
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Login Successful');</script>");
            break;
        }
```

How do I declare the Session to display the firstname of my data without changing the username authentication as (studentID)?

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin with this.  Are you confused by how asp.net session works, or how to query the database?  I hope this code is not for a real site, because it looks like you are setting yourself up for a number of security problems later on, and your site is just going to fall down as soon as you get any significant number of users.  It is just too inefficient to retrieve *all* login records and then loop through them.

Comment: this is just a school project sir,,, I mean how can I display the firstname of the student instead of its userid.

Comment: change your query and fetch single record from the database some thing like this  select firstname,studentid,password from student where studentid="2011018921".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its not a good way to authenticate, but as per your requirement, modify your code as:
change your query to

```
query = "select firstname,studentid,password from student";
```

Then modify your for loop by replacing the upper code as :

```
            string userid = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["StudentID"].ToString();
            string password = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["Password"].ToString();
            string firstname = selectedData.Tables[0].Rows[rowcounter]["FirstName"].ToString();
            if ((username == userid) && (pass == password))
            {
                //This session Login I want to get the firstname of the student
                Session["login"] = userid;
                Session["firstname"] = firstname ;
                Response.Redirect("StudentPage.aspx", true);
                break;
            }
```

use firstname anywhere you want it

Comment: Thanks, It work, I didn't know that you can have multiple sessions in the program. :) thank you.